# how to load UINavigationController from Uiviewcontroller

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I want to load my `UINavController` from my `UIViewController`. My interface details is here.

```
@interface ContactUs : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UIWindow *window;

    IBOutlet UINavigationController *navController;

}

@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navController;

@end

and in implementation ..
```

@synthesize window;

@synthesize navController;

```
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

 -(void)viewDidLoad {

  [window addSubview:navController.view];

  [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    

        NSLog(@":::::::::::::::::::");

}
```

But unfortunate my `UINavigationController` is not loading. I am seeing a blank windows is appearing.

Comment: Did you connect them properly through the interface builder ?

Comment: totally unsure of your approach here, you should get sample code for the apple website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@interface ContactUs : UINavigationViewController {

      IBOutlet UIWindow *window;

      IBOutlet UITextView *textView;
      IBOutlet UIButton *button;

       }

   // Add properties to the all outlets //

     -(IBAction) buttonpressed: (id) sender;
```

And in the implementation - write the code for buttonpressed and you can make use that for whatever your goals are.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the Navigation View controller over the View controller .. Why not use the UINavigationController ?

```
        @interface ContactUs : UINavigationViewController {

          IBOutlet UIWindow *window;

          // IBOutlet UINavigationController *navController; // You do not need this. 

         }
```

Comment: actually this interface is also calling from other windows. and i just change it with UINavigation and i am getting an error "cannot find interface declaration for 'UINavigationViewController', superclass of 'ContactUs' "

Comment: Now error is not coming. I want to make an interface with some text view and one button. What i should to next.Yhanks for reply.